# Who was the Beast Titan before Zeke, and can he turn into different animals?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Who was the beast titan was before Zeke?  Can Zeke change into any animal?

Answer (score 2):

The Beast Titan before Zeke was Tom Ksaver. He was an eldian warrior and researcher.

[Tom Ksaver](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Tom_Ksaver)

Not sure what you mean with your second question, but he has only one titan form.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask was, is every inherit of the beast titan a different animal?

Comment: Not ever specified, but according to the same article there were monkeys, birds, crocodiles, elk, bulls, wolves, snakes, rabbits, dinosaurs, okapis and goats